# How can I remove existing duplicate accounts and records at once?

Tags: duplicate-management

How can I remove duplicate records for accounts and contacts at once from talent rover?I tried to use the dupe eliminator but I would have to search the accounts and contacts one by one and merge.Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found of doing this is to extract into CSV and use Excel to make a list of the duplicates, and then delete the duplicates. The workbench (http://workbench.developerforce.com) gives useful extract/import/delete tools if the dataloader isn't your app of choice.

Alternatively, write some code the the developer console and execute anonymously to remove duplicates...

Comment: I am not aware of apex or visualforce. Is there any way to use the dataloader.io

Comment: Yes, exactly as described above. Export all records => use Excel to find the duplicates => create a csv for the duplicate Ids => delete those use dataloader.